Evaluating a limit at $+\infty $
I need to find an equivalent at $+\infty $ for the expression $ \frac{1}{1+\left( x \cos x \right)^{2}} $ and I think I find one which is probably $\frac{2}{x^{2}}$.
The problem is that I couldn't prove that $ \lim_{x \to +\infty } \frac{x^2}{2(1+\left( x \cos x \right)^{2})}=1 $ and I am not sure if it is true (although Wolfram Alpha gives it as true)
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+x%5E2%2F2%2F%281%2Bx%5E2cos%5E2x%29++as+x-%3Einfinity
Any ideas ?  Thanks in advance !

The limit can't be $1$, as $\cos(x)=0$ at arbitrary large points. At such points the expression will be just $\frac{x^2}{2}$, i.e very large.

The limit can't be $2/x^2,$ because the limit does not depend on $x.$ Are you looking for an asymptote?

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+\left(x\cos x\right)^2}=\ell$$\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac1{x^2}+\cos^2x\right)=\frac1\ell$
$\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos^2x=\frac1\ell$, which is impossible. $\cos^2$ has no limit at $\infty$.

Also the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + (x \cos x)^2}$ doesn't exist: At points at which $\cos x = 0$ this espression is equal to 1 whereas for $\cos x = 1$ it's $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ which goes to 0 as $x \to \infty$, and both cases happen infinitely often.

@ThomasAndrews This seemingly French-speaking user means https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89quivalent, i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition

Thanks ! Now it is much more clear ! Yes I was looking for an asymptote at $ +\infty $ but unfortunately it seems $ \frac{2}{x^2} $  isn't one !

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+\left(x\cos x\right)^2}=\ell$$\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac1{x^2}+\cos^2x\right)=\frac1\ell$
$\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos^2x=\frac1\ell$, which is impossible, since $\cos^2$ has no limit at $\infty$.

The function $f(x)=\frac{2}{x^2}$ for x that goes to $+\infty$ converges to $0$ while the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+(xcosx)^2}$ is an oscillating function so they cannot be equivalent. (In fact, for every neighbourhood of $+\infty$ there are infinite points at which the function g(x)=1, so the $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)$ doesn't exists).
